# "Trying to get property of non-object" sql error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I know other questions already have the answer to this but I don't understand. I've done lots of research and am still confused.

I have a table in my Mysql that I made with PHP My Admin it has three rows (I'll add to these) and 3 columns (id, name and price) I'd like to output the first rows name and id but I keep getting the error

> Trying to get property of non-object;

```
<?php
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sitefiles;charset=utf8mb4','user', 'pass');           
 $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM 1/1/16';
 $results = $db->query($sql);

 if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

How can I get rid of this error? Thank you :)

Comment: '1/1/16' is your table name ?

Comment: Try wrapping `1/1/16` in backticks. I think `$result` is returning `false`.

Comment: I doubt that PDO has `num_rows` or `fetch_assoc()`. When you switch to PDO from other extension, you can't just change the `mysql_connect()` part to PDO.

Comment: 1/1/16 is my table name

Comment: You mixed PDO with mysqli (num_rows, fetch_assoc). Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

Your table name seems to be unusual. Try to use back-ticks to quote it:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM `1/1/16`';
```

Comment: i added these in and the error changed to Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows